# Docker for Desktop runs the Kubernetes - Ip address is not working

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ip, desktop

`kubectl describe node docker-for-desktop`
This gets the IP address of Docker desktop for Windows.

But we run it on browser with `ip:nodeport` it is not working.

`nodeport` - is the port number that we mention in the services file of kubernetes cluster.

Please find `myservice.yaml` file in the code section.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: xxxx

spec:
  # This defines which pods are going to be represented by this Service
  # The service becomes a network endpoint for either other services
  # or maybe external users to connect to (eg browser)
  selector:
    mykey: webapp
    release: "0-5"

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
      #this is port number greater than 30000, and it is port of the Node where this cluster is present.

  type: NodePort
```

`http://<dockerDesktopIdaddress>:<nodeport>`

`nodeport` is the port number in the service file of kubernetes cluster.

always gives error.

Comment: Just edited the question to make it more readable. Maybe you want to describe _which_ error you got so someone can help you.

Comment: Yeah, please add the error description. Docker for Desktop exposes everything on `localhost`, so there should not be issues.

Comment: if someone want to know the error message: 
I've run: curl http://192.168.65.4:30008
and got the error: curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.65.4 port 30008 after 75004 ms: Operation timed out

Answer (score 59):

I had the same issue and the resolution was simple.
curl localhost:$NODE_PORT

Docker for Mac runs on the same host and you can call the service through localhost.

Comment: You're my hero men! I was struggling for whole day to get k8s node external IP, but I should have used simple 'localhost' ::facepalm::. Earlier I was using Minikube and there I had to find out the external IP, on Docker for Windows it's not necessary! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks. This problem makes me really confused, because with Docker Desktop Kubernetes, I can access using localhost:<port>, while with Minikube, I can't do that.

With Minikube, I had to use `minikube service <my-service> --url` to get the URL, then I was able to access it

Answer (score 5):

Another good command to use is **`kubectl describe service your-service-name`**. This way you can see all the kubernetes network objects

```
kubectl describe service configuration-service-service

Name:                     configuration-service-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   none
Annotations:              none
Selector:                 app=configuration-service-deployment
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.109.61.232
LoadBalancer Ingress:     localhost
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30001/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.0.40:8080,10.1.0.41:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Answer (score 3):

Double-check if an External IP is defined for the node.

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

Lookup the LoadBalancer Ingress defined in the service

```
kubectl describe svc service_name
```

Write down the LoadBalancer Ingress: in this case "localhost"

so finally, you can try :

```
curl http://localhost:PORT
```

Comment: `kubectl get nodes -o wide` was a great shortcut to see the internal/external IP for the node and the fact `EXTERNAL-IP` was `<none>`

Answer (score -7):

Docker For Windows , Docker For MAC , or Docker for anything uses minikube for kubernetes , and you need to get the external ip of minikube machine.

You need the external IP instead of internal IP , the kubectl is showing only the internal IP.

```
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ kubectl describe node minikube | grep -i ip
  InternalIP:  10.0.2.15
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        30d
nginx        NodePort    10.107.66.154   <none>        80:32622/TCP   4m
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ curl 10.0.2.15:32622


çççç^C
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ minikube ssh
                         _             _            
            _         _ ( )           ( )           
  ___ ___  (_)  ___  (_)| |/')  _   _ | |_      __  
/' _ ` _ `\| |/' _ `\| || , <  ( ) ( )| '_`\  /'__`\
| ( ) ( ) || || ( ) || || |\`\ | (_) || |_) )(  ___/
(_) (_) (_)(_)(_) (_)(_)(_) (_)`\___/'(_,__/'`\____)

$ 
$ ip a s | grep eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
$ 
$ ip a s | grep eth1
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.99.105/24 brd 192.168.99.255 scope global dynamic eth1
$ 
$ logout
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:test iahmad$ curl 192.168.99.105:32622
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:

As suggested in the comments , if you don't want to see inside the minikube machine , you can use the following command to get the external IP:

```
 minikube ip
```

Comment: Isn't there a `minikube ip` command to get the IP so you don't have to do those extra steps? Also, as the original question appears to be using Dock for Windows it would make sense to help show the correct IP address for that context instead of minikube.

Comment: Docker for windows or docker for anything is the same , I am using Docker for MAC which manage the minikube as well, Docker for anything will need minikube anyway for kubernetes, and that is the correct way to get the correct ip regardless of Docker for anything

Comment: No, they are two different things using different virtualization and management strategies. At least on macOS, Docker for Mac uses xhyve to run the underlying VM while minikube uses VirtualBox. Both will manage and handle networking differently.

Comment: yes , but for users they are the same , especially in the context of this question. I gurarentee that this solution will work on docker for windows as well

Comment: you have run the curl command on the internal ip, How to run the same in windows machine.? As the curl is not available in Windows. If possible could you please help me to get the external ip of docker-for-desktop in windows

Comment: I have run the curl command on both internal and external , the one for internal is not working and the other for external is working. I think you can get the IP on windows the same way. Docker for windows also installs minikube , so you can use `minikube ip` command to get the external ip

Comment: @Rajasekar Murugesan this is how you can install curl: https://chocolatey.org/packages/curl

Comment: "but for users, they are the same, especially in the context of this question. I guarantee that this solution will work on docker for windows as well" - No, this is not the case at all. Docker-for-desktop and minikube are two different ways of locally deploying to a Kubernetes cluster. Additionally, it was especially confusing when you tried to `curl` the Private IP, which is obviously wrong and not what OP asked for.

Comment: Docker for windows doesn't use minikube, in my machine the single node name is 'docker-desktop'